# html tags <u> o <span>?

Tags: html5, css3

Actualmente utilizaba el `span` para seleccionar una parte de mi texto y darle otro estilo, pero recientemente descubrí un tag llamado `u` que tiene el mismo efecto con la misma definición

> Defines text that should be stylistically different from normal text

Alguien sabe ¿Cuándo debería usar cada uno?

Comment: [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u)

Comment: gracias, la diferencia es que el u incluye underline, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo utilizo `<span>` cuando quiero seleccionar como tu dices una parte del texto para añadirle estilos diferentes al resto.

Por lo visto `<u>` tiene una utilidad más específica. Según la [documentación de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u) sirve para subrayar el texto que se encuentra entre las etiquetas.

Sin embargo es mejor no usarlo en casos en que `<u>` se pueda llegar a confundir con `<a>`. Así que yo personalmente usaría siempre `span` y le añadiría el subrayado o cualquier otro estilo que necesitara manualmente.

Comment: si en w3school aparecia la definicion que coloque por eso la duda , gracias